# Can I hang a 'no loitering' sign inside the store?

Tags: word-choice

I want to put up a sign inside (not outside like in the pavement) a supermarket with 'no loitering' on it; by this I'd like to mean if you don't want to buy anything, don't come inside and flirt with your girlfriend, joke around, pace around the supermarket like you're waiting for someone to show up etc. Is it the right sign language to use inside a supermarket?

I'm not sure about this because I've seen this sign in public places mostly in crime-ridden areas. If it's not right or a bit offensive, what do you suggest?

Comment: It is the correct sign to use.  I agree that it can seem a little unfriendly.  You might be able to soften the message by making it something like "Please, no loitering.  Thank you for your cooperation!"  That way the message is still there, but it isn't as curt.

Comment: It's appropriate outside the store, but not usually *inside* the store.  People inside the store are usually considered serous shoppers until proven otherwise, so it would be unfriendly to accuse them of loitering.  However if this is a chronic problem at your store, it would be fine.  Non-loiterers won't get mad :)

Comment: @stangdon & Andrew Thank you both. Then I'd go with 'please no lotering.Thank you for your cooperation' it's polite and direct enough. People are sometimes really inconsiderate.

Comment: @Andrew - For what it's worth, the laundromat downstairs from me has a sign inside that says "This is not a place to hang out.  If you aren't doing laundry, please leave"!